# Update kernel module option on Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, kernel-module

There is a kernel module `hid_apple`, and I need to set its option `fnmode` to 2.

So, I've created `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` file with such content

`options hid_apple fnmode=2`

Then run

```
dracut -f /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```

As I understood now, the value in `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` should be 2, but there is still default value (1). It still there even after reboot.

What is wrong, and how could I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to change the value through sysfs?  I've seen examples like `echo 2 >/sys/xxx`

Comment: Yes, it works, but only until reboot. I need permanent change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `hid_apple` is not compiled as a module - the Fedora kernel has it builtin to the main kernel image.

So you can't use `modprobe.d` to change the options as that only applies to modules.

What you will need to do is to edit `/etc/grub2.cfg` and find the which starts with `linux...` for the kernel you are using and add `hid_apple.fnmode=2` to the end of the line.

Comment: Ok, it works. But what if kernel will be updated? Should I add this options every time kernel update is installed or maybe there is ability to set this permanently for all kernel updates? Thanks

Comment: No - `grubby` (the tool that updates `grub2.cfg` when kernels are added or removed should copy the options over.

Answer (score 3):

That config file isn't available in the initrd. You'll need to pass it as a kernel option at boot, i.e. `hid_apple.fnmode=2`.

Comment: Ok, how can do this? I use grub btw

Comment: Edit the configuration file in `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and put it on the relevant `kernel` line.

Comment: I do not have such file. I do have /boot/grub2/grub.cfg instead but can't find there anything about kernel boot options unfortunately